# fail to Parse a urdf file

Tags: urdf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i can't understand and not working

```
$ .<path>/parser <path>my_robot.urdf
# ./devel/lib/robot_description/parser /src/robot_description/urdf/my_robot.urdf (for example)
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/132196/fail-to-parse-a-urdf-file/) by [M Samir](https://answers.ros.org/users/9326/m-samir/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-02-22

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2014-02-23**:
Could you include the actual error that you are seeing in your question? That would make answering it a bit easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
# ./devel/lib/robot_description/parser /src/robot_description/urdf/my_robot.urdf
```

assuming the binary `parser` actually exists in `./devel/lib/robot_description`, it would seem you pass it an absolute path (ie: `/src/..`). Does that path exist on your system? What is the output of `ls /src/robot_description` for instance?

Additionally, does `robot_description` in `src` contain a directory `urdf` with a `my_robot.urdf` file in it?

Assuming all *yes* to the above, and you are in your `catkin_ws` (or wherever both `devel` and `src` are located), try the following:

```
./devel/lib/robot_description/parser ./src/robot_description/urdf/my_robot.urdf
```

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2014-02-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0